# TypeError: 'Class' object not iterable - flask/sqlalchemy/jinja

Tags: python, html, sqlite, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm retrieving data from a database and I want to put it into a table. I'm using SQLAlchemy and an SQLite database.

Here is the code I have in my routes.py:

```
headings = ('Name', 'Code')
classes = tuple(list(ClassName.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).all()))
print(classes)
return render_template("view.html", headings=headings, classes=classes)
```

Here is the code in view.html:

```
      <div class="view-table">
        <table>
          <tr>
            {% for header in headings %}
            <th>{{ header }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% for row in classes %}
          <tr>
              {% for cell in row %}
                <td>{{ cell }}</td>
              {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
      </div>
```

Whenever I run it, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'Class' object is not iterable
```

I was following this tutorial which is why I changed the list into a tuple: https://youtu.be/mCy52I4exTU

Comment: Doesn't the all() method already return an iterable object? I've never had to wrap the return value of all() in another list or iterable.

Comment: @tutiplain I found the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this.

In my `routes.py`, I did this:

```
classes = Classes.query.filter_by(classAdminID=current_user.id).all()
```

In my `view.html`, I did this:

```
      <div class="view-table">
        <table>
          <tr>
            {% for header in headings %}
            <th>{{ header }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% for row in classes %}
          <tr>
                <td>{{ row.Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.Code }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
      </div>
```

I found the solution in this video: https://youtu.be/hbDRTZarMUw